# Making motorway with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, fun

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
    car/.style={
        scale=.5,minimum width=.1cm,minimum height=.5cm,fill=#1
    }
}
\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {0,10,...,360,350,340,...,0}
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[green!60!black] ([xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm]1,0) rectangle ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=1mm]4,-3);
            \path ([xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm]1,0) -- ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=1mm]4,-3) node[midway,fill=green!40!black,circle,inner sep=.3cm] (a) {};
        \node[fill=green!40!black,circle,inner sep=.1cm,above left=.5cm] at (a) {};
        \node[fill=green!40!black,circle,inner sep=.1cm,above right=.5cm] at (a) {};
        \node[fill=green!40!black,circle,inner sep=.1cm,below left=.5cm] at (a) {};
        \node[fill=green!40!black,circle,inner sep=.1cm,below right=.5cm] at (a) {};
            \draw[double distance=2mm,double=gray] (5,0) -- (0,0) arc(-90:-360:1) --+ (0,-5) arc(0:-270:1) --+ (5,0) arc(90:-180:1) --+ (0,5) arc(180:-90:1);
            \draw[white,densely dashed] (5,0) -- (0,0) arc(-90:-360:1) --+ (0,-5) arc(0:-270:1) --+ (5,0) arc(90:-180:1) --+ (0,5) arc(180:-90:1);
                \node[shift={(0,1)},car=red,rotate=\n] at (\n:1) {};
                \node[shift={(5,1)},car=blue,rotate=-\n] at (-\n:1) {};
                \node[shift={(0,-4)},car=green,rotate=-\n] at (-\n:1) {};
                \node[shift={(5,-4)},car=yellow,rotate=\n] at (\n:1) {};
        \pgfmathsetmacro\factor{\n/360}
            \node[rotate=-90,car=purple] at ($(0,0)!\factor!(5,0)$) {};
            \node[rotate=-90,car=violet] at ($(5,-3)!\factor!(0,-3)$) {};
                \node[car=brown] at ($(4,1)!\factor!(4,-4)$) {};
                \node[car=orange] at ($(1,-3)!\factor!(1,0)$) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

My questions is: How can I make the cars to move along those “arc-parts“ of the track? I would have work with `\ifnum`, but I think it is too laborius …

Comment: Can't you just define the full thing to be one path and then place the cars via `decorations.matkings`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just for fun: a simple way to put the car at an arbitrary position of the road path. To make @DavidCarlisle happy, cars drive on the wrong side of the road.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
    car/.style={
        scale=.5,minimum width=.1cm,minimum height=.5cm,fill=#1
    },
    car on road/.style args={at pos #1 with dist #2 and color #3}{decorate,decoration={markings,
    mark=at position #1 with {\path (-2pt,#2) coordinate (aux1) 
    (2pt,#2) coordinate (aux2);
    \pgftransformreset
    \path let \p1=($(aux2)-(aux1)$),\n1={90+atan2(\y1,\x1)} in
    ($(aux2)!0.5!(aux1)$) node[car=#3,rotate=\n1]{};}}}
}
\begin{document}
\def\roadpath{(5,0) -- (0,0) arc(-90:-360:1) --+ (0,-5) arc(0:-270:1) --+ (5,0) arc(90:-180:1) --+ (0,5) arc(180:-90:1)}
\foreach \n in {0,5,...,355}
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[green!60!black] ([xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm]1,0) rectangle ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=1mm]4,-3);
            \path ([xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm]1,0) -- ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=1mm]4,-3) node[midway,fill=green!40!black,circle,inner sep=.3cm] (a) {};
        \node[fill=green!40!black,circle,inner sep=.1cm,above left=.5cm] at (a) {};
        \node[fill=green!40!black,circle,inner sep=.1cm,above right=.5cm] at (a) {};
        \node[fill=green!40!black,circle,inner sep=.1cm,below left=.5cm] at (a) {};
        \node[fill=green!40!black,circle,inner sep=.1cm,below right=.5cm] at (a) {};
            \draw[double distance=3mm,double=gray] \roadpath;
            \draw[white,densely dashed] \roadpath;
        \pgfmathsetmacro\factor{\n/360}
        \path[car on road=at pos {\factor} with dist 1mm and color red] \roadpath;
        \path[car on road=at pos {1-\factor} with dist -1mm and color blue] \roadpath;
        \pgfmathsetmacro\factor{mod(\n/360+0.5,1)}
        \path[car on road=at pos {\factor} with dist 1mm and color cyan] \roadpath;
        \path[car on road=at pos {1-\factor} with dist -1mm and color orange] \roadpath;
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the *wrong side of the road* :-D

Comment: @egreg Of course, in Italy they drive on the right side. And since in the UK they drive on the opposite side, and since the opposite of right is wrong, there is only one possible conclusion ;-)

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30630373#30630373

Comment: @marmot Very nice comments. +1.