# Animate an airplane in Beamer

Tags: beamer, animations

For my (beamer) presentation (relating to airplanes) I want an animation of an airplane. I was hoping there would be a way for the airplane to move across the screen (or any other motion will do as well ). For instance, see 09:45 in this video [moving airplane in powerpoint](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tFd9nHgRKSc) The airplane can look like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114783/draw-an-aircraft-with-tikz) , feel free to include any image of airplane.

This is all I have right now (a simple image of airplane in beamer template)

```
 \documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
        \usepackage{fontawesome}
        \mode<presentation>
        {\usetheme{Singapore}
        \setbeamercovered{transparent}
        }
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \title{Beamer Example}
    \author{Author}
    \subject{Presentation Programs} 
    \institute[ University]{
        Department of XZ\\
         University}        
    \begin{document}        
        \section{Outline}               
        \frame[label=exampleframe]{
            \frametitle{Example}                
            \faPlane            
        }           
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Example using Fontawesome plane (**click** on the image to see animation):

[image]

**Update**: The Beamer part, to fulfill the request completely.

To become **independent from Adobe** products, the whole presentation can be made in SVG format (**Click** to start presentation, **<kbd>F11</kbd>** for full-screen, navigate with **<kbd>PgUp</kbd>** and **<kbd>PgDown</kbd>**; a Blink-based browser [Chromium, Chrome, Opera] may be needed for the background gradient to be rendered correctly):

[image]

**Standalone animation** LaTeX input:

Update: example extended (softer take-off and landing) and improved (node placing along path, as shown by user @Hafid).

```
\documentclass{standalone}                    % animated PDF
%\documentclass[dvisvgm,preview]{standalone}  % animated SVG: latex + dvisvgm --font-format=woff --bbox=preview --zoom=-1  
%\documentclass[export]{standalone}           % multipage PDF

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{tikz,animate}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\fpEval\fp_eval:n % expandable flt-point calculation with L3
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \begin{animateinline}[
        autoplay,controls,
        begin={\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.85]
                 \coordinate (a)  at (110:15); \coordinate (b)  at (70:15);
                 \node [anchor=north east] at (a) {A}; \node [anchor=north west] at (b) {B};
                 \useasboundingbox (a) node [anchor=north east] {A} arc [start angle=110,end angle=70,radius=15] (b) node [anchor=north west] {B};},
        end={\end{tikzpicture}}
    ]{24}
    \multiframe{161}{iPos=0+1}{%
      \path[draw] (a) arc [start angle=110,end angle=70,radius=15] (b) node [pos=\fpEval{0.5*(1-cosd(180*\iPos/160))},sloped,rotate=-45]{\faPlane};
    }
    \newframe
    \multiframe{19}{iAng=45+10}{%
      \path[draw] (a) arc [start angle=110,end angle=70,radius=15] (b) node [pos=1,sloped,rotate=-\iAng]{\faPlane};
    }
    \newframe*
    \multiframe{161}{iPos=0+1}{%
      \path[draw] (a) arc [start angle=110,end angle=70,radius=15] (b) node [pos=\fpEval{0.5*(1+cosd(180*\iPos/160))},sloped,rotate=135]{\faPlane};
    }
    \newframe
    \multiframe{19}{iAng=135+-10}{%
      \path[draw] (a) arc [start angle=110,end angle=70,radius=15] (b) node [pos=0,sloped,rotate=\iAng]{\faPlane};
    }
    \end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

**Presentation (`beamer`**-class **)** LaTeX input. Compile with

```bsh
latex presentation.tex
latex presentation.tex
dvisvgm --font-format=woff --bbox=papersize --zoom=-1 -p1,- presentation
```

```latex
\documentclass[dvisvgm,hypertex,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{tikz,animate}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\fpEval\fp_eval:n % expandable flt-point calculation with L3
\ExplSyntaxOff

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% PageDown, PageUp key event handling; navigation symbols
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[totpages]{zref}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{%
    \special{dvisvgm:raw
      <defs>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      <![CDATA[
        document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
          if(e.key=='PageDown'){
            \ifnum\thepage<\ztotpages
              document.location.replace('\jobname-\the\numexpr\thepage+1\relax.svg');%
            \fi
          }else if(e.key=='PageUp'){
            \ifnum\thepage>1
              document.location.replace('\jobname-\the\numexpr\thepage-1\relax.svg');%
            \fi%
          }
        });
      ]]>
      </script>
      </defs>
    }%
  }%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeftForeground{%
    \raisebox{-\dimexpr\height+0.5ex\relax}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[\paperwidth][r]{%
      \normalsize\color{structure!40!}%
      \ifnum\thepage>1%
        \href{\jobname-\the\numexpr\thepage-1\relax.svg}{\faArrowLeft}%
      \else%  
        \textcolor{lightgray}{\faArrowLeft}%  
      \fi\hspace{0.5ex}%
      \ifnum\thepage<\ztotpages%
        \href{\jobname-\the\numexpr\thepage+1\relax.svg}{\faArrowRight}%
      \else%
        \textcolor{lightgray}{\faArrowRight}%  
      \fi%
      \hspace{0.5ex}%
    }}%
  }%  
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{Fasten Seat Belts}
\subtitle{Use a Web browser and press \framebox{F11}}
\author{AlexG}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}{Animation}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{animateinline}[
        autoplay,controls,
        begin={\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.95]
                 \coordinate (a)  at (110:15); \coordinate (b)  at (70:15);
                 \node [anchor=north east] at (a) {A}; \node [anchor=north west] at (b) {B};
                 \useasboundingbox (a) node [anchor=north east] {A} arc [start angle=110,end angle=70,radius=15] (b) node [anchor=north west] {B};},
        end={\end{tikzpicture}}
    ]{24}
    \multiframe{161}{iPos=0+1}{%
      \path[draw] (a) arc [start angle=110,end angle=70,radius=15] (b) node [pos=\fpEval{0.5*(1-cosd(180*\iPos/160))},sloped,rotate=-45]{\faPlane};
    }
    \newframe
    \multiframe{19}{iAng=45+10}{%
      \path[draw] (a) arc [start angle=110,end angle=70,radius=15] (b) node [pos=1,sloped,rotate=-\iAng]{\faPlane};
    }
    \newframe*
    \multiframe{161}{iPos=0+1}{%
      \path[draw] (a) arc [start angle=110,end angle=70,radius=15] (b) node [pos=\fpEval{0.5*(1+cosd(180*\iPos/160))},sloped,rotate=135]{\faPlane};
    }
    \newframe
    \multiframe{19}{iAng=135+-10}{%
      \path[draw] (a) arc [start angle=110,end angle=70,radius=15] (b) node [pos=0,sloped,rotate=\iAng]{\faPlane};
    }
    \end{animateinline}  
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While compiling using latex, I am not able to view any animation. Am I missing something?

Comment: You need Acrobat Reader as PDF viewer.

Comment: Thanks @AlexG. I'll have to install it then. Wont any other debian friendly PDF Viewer do?

Comment: @GermanShepherd there are  a few pdf viewers that have good emulation of adobe internals on windows each adobe collaborator may have some good features the better ones are bluebeam  and foxit and the lightest contender are the tracker products most of those 3 have products that should handle this form of animation well

Comment: Firefox, Chromium. In the case of SVG output. (As animation in my answer.)

Comment: @AlexG, Firefox does render the image animation. I 'll still need Acrobat/ some other PDF Viewer for my presentation I believe. I want the plane to fly when the slide is loaded.

Comment: @GermanShepherd looking deeper the only contender for Linux seems to be foxit reader but their market is in order of support Win Mac Nix so support may fall by the wayside, in general the best native contender is Okular (mainly to run movie sequence) but here is a descriptive sequenced graphic that should run in Okular (In SumatraPDF I only see it as a number of stills that I have to hold spacebar in order to see a moving presentation.) https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~mb13434/aniexl.html the only  advice seen is to run win acrobat reader under wine. but I think most view that as a workaround.

Comment: @KJO Thank you so much. Acrobat with wine seems better to me.

Comment: @GermanShepherd : Why not getting completely independent from Adobe? See edit.

Answer (score 16):

With `decorations.markings` you can transport the plane along any path and it will always be rotated to be a tangent of the path (without you having to do that manually).

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\mode<presentation>
{\usetheme{Singapore}
 \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,calc}
\title{Beamer Example}
\author{Author}
\subject{Presentation Programs} 
\institute[ University]{
    Department of XZ\\
     University}        
\newcount\myangle    
\begin{document}        
\section{Outline}               
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Example}
\transduration{4}
\animate<2-21>
\animatevalue<2-21>{\myangle}{0}{19}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
plane/.style={code={\fill (-0.6,0.2) -- (-0.5,0) -- (-0.6,-0.2)
-- (-0.4,-0.2) -- (-0.3,-0.1)-- (-0.1,-0.15) -- (-0.2,-0.5) -- (00.05,-0.5)
-- (0.15,-0.2) to[out=0,in=-90] (0.5,0) to[out=90,in=180]  (0.15,0.2)
-- (00.05,0.5) -- (-0.2,0.5) -- (-0.1,0.15) -- (-0.3,0.1) -- (-0.4,0.2); }}}
\path[use as bounding box] (-5.5,-4.5) rectangle (2.5,3.5);
\draw[postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
mark=at position \myangle/20 with {\path let \p1=($(current bounding
box.east)-(current bounding box.west)$),
\n1={-atan2(\y1,\x1)} in  pic[rotate=\n1]{plane};}}}] (-5,0) to (2,0) arc(90:-180:2)
--++(0,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This uses the beamer built-in animation facilities (as in [Hafid's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475501/121799)), but can be combined with `\animateinline` (see [Raaja's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475480/121799) and [AlexG's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475482/121799)).

The animated gif was created via

```
 convert -density 300 -delay 34 -loop 0 -alpha remove multipage.pdf animated.gif
```

as explained [in this great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919/121799).

Or a 3D like version where the plane flies out of the beamer plane. (Before giving the presentation, please contact the organizers for a safety briefing. ;-)

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{\usetheme{Singapore}
 \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,calc}
\title{Beamer Example}
\author{Author}
\subject{Presentation Programs} 
\institute[ University]{
    Department of XZ\\
     University}        
\newcount\mydist     
\begin{document}        
\section{Outline}               
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Example}
\transduration{4}
\animate<2-22>
\animatevalue<2-22>{\mydist}{0}{20}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
plane/.style={code={\fill (-0.6,0.2) -- (-0.5,0) -- (-0.6,-0.2)
-- (-0.4,-0.2) -- (-0.3,-0.1)-- (-0.1,-0.15) -- (-0.2,-0.5) -- (00.05,-0.5)
-- (0.15,-0.2) to[out=0,in=-90] (0.5,0) to[out=90,in=180]  (0.15,0.2)
-- (00.05,0.5) -- (-0.2,0.5) -- (-0.1,0.15) -- (-0.3,0.1) -- (-0.4,0.2); }}}
\path[use as bounding box] (-5.25,-4.5) rectangle (2.25,3.5);
\draw[postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
mark=at position \mydist/20 with {\path let \p1=($(current bounding
box.east)-(current bounding box.west)$),
\n1={-atan2(\y1,\x1)} in  (0,0)
pic[rotate=\n1,scale={0.3+0.7*sin(9*\mydist)},gray!20]{plane}
(${0.01+0.04*sin(9*\mydist)}*($(current bounding
box.north east)-(current bounding box.south west)$)$)
pic[rotate=\n1,scale={0.3+0.7*sin(9*\mydist)}]{plane};}}}] (-5,0) to (2,0) arc(90:-180:2)
--++(0,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: neat as usual and only niggle is the shift of focus at start :-) However my question is out of interest what steps did you use to convert to gif ?

Comment: @KJO I added that information (and also removed the initial kick;-).

Comment: +1 more and more if I could

Comment: Certainly the best solution here. +1

Comment: @marmot You never fail to amaze me. This is beautiful.

Comment: @AlexG I don't think this is the "best" solution. All I did was to use methods pioneered by you and to recycle something I have done [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/458399/121799).

Comment: @marmot I was also looking for this place-a-node-along-a-path thing, but couldn't find it.

Comment: @AlexG These things have been used in the [Christmas extravaganza](https://vimeo.com/305374856), with the source code being available at https://github.com/samcarter/Extravanganza2018. The "CarLaTex driving" thing was making use of it. There was also a "Eulen nach Athen tragen" sketch, but we left it out, sob ...

Comment: Flying plane in 2.5D, great!!!

Comment: How do you add  animations to your answers?

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda "The animated gif was created via
 `convert -density 300 -delay 34 -loop 0 -alpha remove multipage.pdf animated.gif`
as explained in [this great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919/121799)".

Answer (score 8):

Another solution using `\animate` command provided by the `beamer` package

```
    \documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
        \usepackage{fontawesome}
        \usepackage{tikz}
        \mode<presentation>
        {\usetheme{Singapore}
        \setbeamercovered{transparent}
        }
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \title{Beamer Example}
    \author{Author}
    \subject{Presentation Programs} 
    \institute[ University]{
        Department of XZ\\
         University}        
    \begin{document}        
        \section{Outline}               
        \frame[label=exampleframe]{
            \frametitle{Example} 
            See the plane flying
            \newcount\p
            \animate<2-10>
            \animatevalue<2-10>{\p}{0}{100}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \path(0,0)rectangle(0.75\paperwidth,-0.75\paperheight);
            \path[draw](0,0)..controls +(30:2) and +(40:2)..+(4,-1) node [pos=\p/100,sloped,rotate=-45,allow upside down]{\faPlane};

            \end{tikzpicture}
        }           
    \end{document}
```

Comment: It was this method of positioning a node along the path I was looking for. Thanks,  +1!

Comment: @AlexG Very pleased to know that my answer is helpful to you

Answer (score 7):

A starting point for your pursuit:

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\mode<presentation>
{\usetheme{Singapore}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\title{Beamer Example}
\author{Author}
\subject{Presentation Programs} 
\institute[ University]{
    Department of XZ\\
    University}        

%% you need these
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}        
    \section{Outline}               
    \frame[label=exampleframe]{
        \frametitle{Example}                
        \faPlane            
    }           

\begin{frame}[c]

\begin{center}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\N{10}

\begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{5} 
    \multiframe{6}{iPosition=0+1}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[circle,draw=black] (t1) at (0,0) {};
        \node (tx) at (\iPosition,0) {\rotatebox{-45}{\faPlane}};
        \draw[-]  (t1.center) -- (tx.center);
        \node[circle,draw=black] (t2) at (5,0) {};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{animateinline}
\end{center}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**PS** With `@marmot's` suggestion:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Raaja. This seems good to me.. I 'll try to play around with this.

Comment: @Raaja a dirty way for make a .gif is using a screen capture software like Apowersoft

Comment: @GermanShepherd You are welcome!

Comment: @vipa I will try to play with that, thnx for the suggestion ;)

Comment: @Raaja Very nice and good. You airplane is very fast. :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you. I'll slide you a secret, my TiKzplane possess time-warping capabilities `;-)`.

Answer (score 6):

Slightly modified from https://github.com/samcarter/Extravanganza2018/blob/master/paulo/MaryDuck/MaryDuck.tex by @PauloCereda

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikzducks}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,
 decoration={markings, mark=at position \thepage/\insertdocumentendpage with {
    \begin{scope}[xscale=-1]
    \duck
    \fill[orange] (0.7331,0.5229) .. controls (1.8688,-0.6326) and (2.2337,0.0383) .. (1.2819,0.7331) -- cycle;
    \fill[brown] (1.3848,1.6771) .. controls (1.2665,2.2823) and (0.5559,2.2697) .. (0.4000,1.6455) .. controls (0.5711,1.6714) and (0.8503,1.6562) .. (0.9926,1.6247) .. controls (0.9703,1.4641) and (1.0307,1.0718) .. (1.1444,1.0104) .. controls (1.3485,0.9002) and (1.4461,1.4498) .. (1.3848,1.6771) -- cycle;
    \fill[gray] (0.9153,1.4857) -- (0.9472,1.6278) -- (1.3926,1.5288) -- (1.3840,1.4228) -- cycle;
    \fill[gray] (0.6484,1.6773) -- (0.6601,1.7155) -- (0.7558,1.6863) -- (0.7441,1.6480) -- cycle;
    \draw[gray,fill=black] (0.83,1.57) circle (0.135);
    \draw[gray,fill=black] (0.54,1.65) circle (0.12);
    \end{scope}
}}
]
\path[postaction=decorate]
  ($(current page.north west)+(-1,0)$) to[out=-30,in=90] 
  (current page.center) to[out=-90,in=180,looseness=6,distance=4cm]
  (current page.center) to[out=0,in=160]
  (current page.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\pause[50]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do ducks need artificial wings?

Comment: Also, downward loopings are dangerous!

Comment: I have always been especially fond of a plane duck!

Comment: @AlexG If you are a duck on a duck plane you can pull off downward loopings, after all you don't need a parachute in case something goes wrong but can just fly yourself :)

Comment: @R.Schumacher duck plane: https://i.imgur.com/HzsQI5i.jpg :)

Comment: im a big fan of your tikzduckz package

Comment: @georg That's nice to hear! Thank you!